# SQL Query, join returning a list

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables:

- **tblEmployee**

  employeeId int PK

  name varchar(50)
- **tblSkill**

  skillId int PK

  name
- **tblEmployeeSkill**

  employeeSkill int PK

  employeeId int FK

  skillId int FK

I want to run a query that will return all of the skills and whether a particular user has them. ie:

SQL| no

C# | yes

ruby | no

where userId = 1

any help please?

Comment: what RDBMS you are using? SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my understanding, you want to distribute **all skills to all users**. That's the reason why the query below has a subquery that produces cartesian product. The result of the product is then join back with tables `tblEmployee` and `tblSkill` so to be able to get their respective names.

And the last part which is `LEFT JOIN` so to check if a certain skill to the user is present on table `tblEmployeeSkill`. When the result is `NULL`, then it simply means that the user hasn't that skill yet.

```
SELECT  y.name EmployeeName,
        z.name SkillName,
        CASE WHEN xx.skillID IS NULL
            THEN 'NO'
            ELSE 'YES'
        END status
FROM
    (
        SELECT  a.employeeID, b.skillID
        FROM    tblEmployee a 
                CROSS JOIN tblSkill b
    ) x
    INNER JOIN  tblEmployee y
        ON x.employeeID = y.employeeID
    INNER JOIN tblSkill z
        ON x.skillID = z.skillID
    LEFT JOIN tblEmployeeSkill xx
        ON  x.employeeID = xx.employeeID AND
            x.skillID = xx.skillID
-- WHERE   x.employeeId = 1   -- uncomment this if you
                              -- want to select only one user
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5376c/8)

Comment: I have not seen SQL Fiddle before its a great idea!

Answer (score 3):

A simple LEFT JOIN against the list of skills should suffice for this.  If the employee does not have an entry matching that skill, the primary key for that entry will be NULL:

```
SELECT tblSkill.name, 
       CASE 
         WHEN tblEmployeeSkill.employeeSkill IS NULL THEN 'no' 
         ELSE 'yes' 
       END as hasSkill
FROM tblSkill
LEFT JOIN tblEmployeeSkill 
  ON tblSkill.skillId = tblEmployeeSkill.skillId 
  AND tblEmployeeSkill.employeeId = 1
```

Comment: no, this will not return all skills to all users. the OP wants it. that's why `CROSS JOIN` is required.

Comment: @JW.: The OP wants to check 'a particular user' as I read it...  No CROSS JOIN should be needed for this.

Comment: a particular user, right. but how will you match all skill to the user? and which in this case which the user want. how will you get `YES/NO` status from it?

Comment: @JW.: The `tblSkill` table is a list of all skills.  This is not a complicated query, and I think my answer explains how it works.  The OP used an example of `WHERE userId = 1`. In my solution the employeeId is used as this filter within the LEFT JOIN

Comment: The question states: `I want to run a query that will **return all of the skills and whether a particular user has them**`

Comment: @JW.: using your sqlfiddle schema here are the [results with my solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5376c/9).